# JObject.Load JsonReaderException

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have the such json:

```
{  
   "_id":{  
      "$oid":"5b7bc6acc223c11047485dd5"
   },
   "id":"28679e7d-0bca-40b0-b033-044df2bb1b47",
   "type":"some string"   
}
```

and such class:

```
public class Foo 
{
    private readonly JObject _json;

    internal Foo(JObject data)
    {
        _json = data;
    }

    public override Guid Id => (_json["id"]).ToObject<Guid>();

    public override string Type => _json["type"]?.ToString();
}
```

I would like to deserizalize this string to `Foo` instance. I have the following deserializer:

```
public class FooConverter : JsonConverter<Foo>
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Foo value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteRaw(value.GetJsonData().ToString());
    }

    public override Foo ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Foo existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var obj = JObject.Load(reader); // Here's an exception
        return new Foo(obj);
    }
}
```

As you can see my json has field `_id` which `Foo` doesn't. When I call

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(jsonString);
```

I get this exception:

> 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: O. Path '_id', line 1, position 10.''

Is it possible to avoid this exception and load json correctly?

Comment: I don't think the name of `_id` is the problem here. It's most likely `$oid`. Is there a special reason why you are creating a `JObject` and not deserializing the json directly into the class?

Comment: Is `$oid` supposed to be a guid as well? You'll probably have problems trying to deserialize 2 Guids with different formats

Comment: @RuiJarimba _id and $oid shoud be ignored

Comment: Are you using the `JObject` property of `Foo` anywhere else beside the getters of `Id` and `Type`?

Comment: This code just works. Read [ask] and create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The following json string

```
{  
   "_id":{  
      "$oid":"5b7bc6acc223c11047485dd5"
   },
   "id":"28679e7d-0bca-40b0-b033-044df2bb1b47",
   "type":"some string"   
}
```

Can be mapped to the following classes:

```
public class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty("_id")]
    public FooId FooId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class FooId
{
    [JsonProperty("$oid")]
    public string Oid { get; set; }
}
```

Testing the code:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"{  
   ""_id"":{  
      ""$oid"":""5b7bc6acc223c11047485dd5""
   },
   ""id"":""28679e7d-0bca-40b0-b033-044df2bb1b47"",
   ""type"":""some string""   
}";

        var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you doesn't need the `private readonly JObject _json;` property elsewhere than the getters of `Id` and `Type` You can simplify your code by deserializing directly to `Foo` like this:

Change your `Foo` class:

```
public class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public override Guid Id {get;set;}

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public override string Type {get;set;}
}
```

The `JsonProperty` attributes are needed because the element keys in your json string aren't the same as in your `Foo` class (case sensitive).

Then you can deserialize the json like this:

```
var json = "some json";
var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);
```

The json `_id` element just gets ignored.

While doing it like this you can ommit creating a custom converter `FooConverter` and your `Foo` class is much cleaner.